# Searching for *exact* string on Google or other search engines

Tags: search, google-search, string

Google advanced search says that to search for an exact word or phrase, put the word or phrase in quotations, e.g. "rat terrier"

However this doesn't work the way I want/expected for certain kinds of strings. For example a search for the string m/in returns lots of pages which don't have that string on them, while ignoring (at least in early results) pages that do.

So: how can I do a search so that the top results are pages containing the exact string? Is there a clever way to force Google to return exact matches at the top? Or is there another search engine which does this? (I tried a few without any luck.)

Comment: Unfortunately google generally ignores punctuation, so I don't think this is doable with google.  (See https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en&ref_topic=3180167&vid=0-1057747787144-1550032925079&visit_id=636856297474948894-4093662962&rd=1)

Comment: Another alternative to SymbolHound is PublicWWW: https://publicwww.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try your search with the [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) search engine.

Comment: This is in the right direction, but doesn't seem to work that well - if my little test text m/in is any indication.  I know that string is on pages not being returned by SymbolHound